# $(1+x+x^2)^n=P_0+P_{1}x + P_{2}x^2+ \cdots +P_{2n}x^{2n}$ Prove that,$ P_0+P_{3}+P_{6}+ \cdots =3^{(n-1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

***Let's say $$ S_n = (1+x+x^2)^n $$
n=1 $$S_1=1+x+x^2$$
n=2 $$S_2=1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4$$
n=3 $$S_3=1+3x+6x^2+7x^3+6x^4+3x^5+x^6$$
n=4 $$S_4=1+4x+10x^2+16x^3+19x^4+16x^5+10x^6+4x^7+x^8$$***
**By taking coefficients of the $S_n$ we can form this type of triangle similar to *Pascal's Trinagle***
$$\begin{matrix}
&&&&&&&&&1\\
&&&&&&&1&&1&&1\\
&&&&&1&&2&&3&&2&&1\\
&&&&1&&3&&6&&7&&6&&3&&1\\
&&1&&4&&10&&16&&19&&16&10&&4&&1
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. It will be better if you post context _e.g._ the source of the problem, what you have tried, etc. (You can click on the edit button below the post to do so!) Otherwise the post will attract downvotes and closevotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote $\omega$ as the third root of unity .
Therefore , ${\omega}^3 = 1$.

And ${\omega}^2 + \omega + 1=0$.

Now , $$(1+x+x^2)^n= P_0 + P_1x + P_2{x^2} + \ldots + P_{2n}x^{2n}....(1)$$

Putting $x=1$ in equation (1) ,we get

$$3^n= P_0 + P_1x + P_2{x^2} + \ldots + P_{2n}x^{2n}....(2)$$

Putting $x= \omega$ in (1) we get

$$(1+\omega + {\omega}^2)^n= 0 = P_0 + P_1\omega + P_2{\omega^2} + \ldots + P_{2n}\omega^{2n}....(3)$$

Putting $x=\omega^2$ in equation (1) we get ,

$$(1+\omega^2  + \omega^4)^n = 0 =P_0 + P_1\omega^2 + P_2{\omega^4} + \ldots + P_{2n}\omega^{4n} ....(4)$$

Adding equations (2) ,(3) and (4) we get ,

$$3^n = 3( P_0 + P_3 + P_6 + \ldots )$$

Therefore , $$(P_0 + P_3 + P_6 + \ldots ) = \frac{3^n}{3}= 3^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 7):

We define $\xi:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $P(x)=(1+x+x^2)^n$. Observe, that $$P(1)+P(\xi)+P(\xi^2)=3(P_0+P_3+\ldots).$$
This holds for all real polynomials. Just prove it for monomials. Further we know $P(1)=3^n$ and $P(\xi)=P(\xi^2)=0$, because $\xi$ and $\xi^2$ are roots of $1+x+x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can also prove this based on what you've already observed about the relationship with Pascal's Triangle:

> Let $ A(i,n) = \sum P_{3k + i }$ for the coefficients of $ ( 1 + x + x^2 ) ^n$.
> Then show by induction that
> $$ A(0, n ) = A(1, n) = A(2, n) = A(0, n-1 ) + A(1, n-1) + A(2,n-1) = 3^{n-1}.$$

In fact, the $(1+x)^n$ analogue is the well known fact that the sum of the even terms and odd terms in Pascal's triangle are both $2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let define

$$(1+x+x^2)^{n}=P_0(n)+P_{1}(n)x + P_{2}(n)x^2 \pmod {x^3}$$

with

- $P_0(n)= P_0+P_3+\cdots$
- $P_1(n)= P_1+P_4+\cdots$
- $P_2(n)= P_2+P_5+\cdots$

therefore it is easy to check that

$$(1+x+x^2)^{n+1}=P_0(n+1)+P_{1}(n+1)x + P_{2}(n+1)x^2=$$

$$=\left[P_0(n)+P_{1}(n) + P_{2}(n)\right]+\left[P_0(n)+P_{1}(n) + P_{2}(n)\right]x+\left[P_0(n)+P_{1}(n) + P_{2}(n)\right]x^2$$

and since $P_0(1)=P_1(1)=P_2(1)=1$, we easily obtain that

- $P_0(1)=1$
- $P_0(2)=3P_0(1)=3$
- $P_0(3)=3P_0(2)=3^2P_0(1)=3^2$
- $\cdots$
- $P_0(n)=3^{n-1}$